# Same route path with different component in React

Tags: reactjs, routes

I need a View component and an Edit component. Depends on conditions, a button needs to go View page or Edit page.

I set a Route like below.
The problem is the paths are the same.

```
<Route exact path='/users/:user_id' component={Users.Edit} />
<Route exact path='/users/:user_id' component={Users.View} />
```

In page, I have links like below

```
(type = "A") ? <Link to="users/1">view</Link> : <Link to="users/1">edit</Link>
```

For now, the router has same path so the button goes to the Edit component.

Is there any good react way I can call Edit component or View component?
or Do I need to just like below?

```
<Route exact path='/users/:user_id' component={Users.Edit} />
<Route exact path='/users/:user_id/view' component={Users.View} />
```

Comment: Why do you set up `Route`s if you don't actually need routes? URL doesn't change, so why use routes? You can just have a state variable that points to either `View` or `Edit`, and render your component based on that.

Comment: You could just toggle the view i.e conditionally render instead of using Routes

Answer (score 1):

I think this looks ok

```
<Route exact path='/users/:user_id' component={Users.Edit} />
<Route exact path='/users/:user_id/view' component={Users.View} />
```

But usual practice for CRUD to define routes in this way

```
<Route exact path='/users/' component={Users.List} />
<Route exact path='/users/create' component={Users.Create} />
<Route exact path='/users/:user_id' component={Users.View} />
<Route exact path='/users/edit/:user_id' component={Users.Edit} />
```

Comment: So, at the end of the day, which would be the better way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like you suggest with the /view suffix, but I would suggest combining the `/users/:user_id` with the `Users.View` component, and the `/users/:user_id/edit` with the `Users.Edit` component.

The reason 1 exact url cannot be handled based on conditions is when you open that url from let's say an e-mail, there is no way of telling which component to render.

*There is a way, but it's harder than adding just 2 routes.*

You might want to change the view/edit decision to a query param on 1 route, but then you have to create a new wrapper component around `Users.Edit` and `Users.View` to handle the decision based on the query param. So your route should look like

```
<Route exact path='/users/:user_id' component={Users.EditOrViewDecision} />
```

Next you can create links to that route by passing search to the `Link`

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/users/1',
  search: '?view=edit'
}}/>
```

But this way you still have to manage your decision in the `EditOrViewDecision` based on the `?view=edit` query which component you want to display.